# Editing a correlogram

Tags: r, pearson-correlation

I'm trying to create a correlogram using corrgram package

```
library(corrgram)
data("iris")

col.corrgram <- function(ncol) {
  colorRampPalette(
    c("darkgoldenrod4","burlywood1","darkkhaki","darkgreen")
  )(ncol)
}

corrgram(
  iris,
  order = TRUE,
  lower.panel = panel.shade,
  upper.panel = panel.pts,
  col.regions = col.corrgram
)
```

The names of variables appear in the diagonal panel. I need the names on the left and bottom of the correlogram and to create a histogram of each variable in the diagonal panel.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: This one is using the "Iris" file so data can be taken from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
# From 'pairs' help page for plotting histogram
panel.hist <- function(x, ...)
{
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
  h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
  breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
  y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
  rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, col = "cyan", ...)
}

# Load library
library(corrgram)

# Plot correlogram
tst <- corrgram(mtcars,
         order=TRUE, 
         diag.panel = panel.hist, 
         upper.panel = panel.pts,
         lower.panel = panel.shade,
         text.panel = NULL,
         outer.labels = list(bottom = list(labels = colnames(mtcars)), 
                             left = list(labels = colnames(mtcars))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I found the same thing. Works well enough.